# How to integrate real-time data into d3 charts in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, real-time

I'm going to create a real-time data chart with D3. Frame work is React, but the data value that keeps changing comes only once. What should I do to stack up the data?

Is it because of the useEffect? But when I do it, I have to use d3 in this hook so that there is no error. And if I write xValue in the deps of useEffect, I keep getting only one value.

```
const StreamingGraphWithD3 = ({contentsData, chartSetting}) => {

const ref = useRef();
const xValue = contentsData.tem

useEffect(() => {
    D3Chart(ref, xValue)
}, [])

return (
    <div ref={ref} id={"svg_data1"}>

    </div>
)
```

}

Below is the information about d3 svg.

```
const D3Chart = (ref, xValue) => {

ref.current.innerHTML = '';


const currentElement = ref.current;


let n = 150,
    duration = 200,
    now = new Date(Date.now() - duration)


const data = d3.range(n).map(function () {
    return 0;
});


const margin = {top: 100, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30}

const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right

const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom


const svg = d3.select(currentElement)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

const x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration])
    .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-100, 100])
    .range([height, 0]);



const yGrid = () => {
    return d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(10)
}


svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "Ygrid")
    .attr('stroke-opacity', '0.2')
    .call(yGrid()
        .tickSize(-width)
        .tickFormat("")
    )

const line =
    d3.line()
        .x((d, i) => x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration))
        .y((d, i) => y(d))
        .curve(d3.curveBasis);

const path = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .append("path")
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', '#FF7F7FFF')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line");


svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


const axis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "Xaxis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
    .call(x.axis = d3.axisBottom(x));


svg.append('g')
    .attr('class','Yaxis')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

tick();

function tick() {

    now = new Date();
    x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);
    y.domain([-100, 100]);

    data.push(xValue);


    svg.select(".line")
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("transform", null); 


    axis.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .call(x.axis);


    path.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr("transform", `translate( ${x(now - (n - 1) * duration)})`)
        .on("end", tick);

    data.shift();

}

return(
    <div>

    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You're having problems because if you invoke that `useEffect` for every data change, you're completely throwing away the entire chart, that includes all the scales and domains you've calculated.

I would make 2 changes:

1. Pass your data into you're React component (or store it in a `useState`) and provide that to the chart. Then you're in control of the full data set.
2. Call a second `useEffect`, one that basically triggers the `tick` code but leaves the rest of the chart untouched. To achieve this you may have to put your `D3Chart` instance into state so you can access it.

Comment: After seeing your feedback, I only ran tick code in the first useEffect and wrote the code that configured the D3 chart in the second useEffect. However, the svg, or line that makes up the chart is also used in the tick code and must be exported. So I modularized the codes and import them, but I don't think it's working properly. How do I write the D3 chart code in the second useEffect?